# How to order html elements in the same order as array using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to order html elements in the same order as arrayData.

JavaScript

```
    var arrayData = [59, 56, 57];
```

HTML

```
    <div class="selectize-input">
        <div class="item" data-value="56">Dog</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="57">Rabbit</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="59">Cat</div>
    </div>
```

I want the result like this.

```
    <div class="selectize-input">
        <div class="item" data-value="59">Cat</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="56">Dog</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="57">Rabbit</div>
    </div>
```

Is there any good way to achive this?
Thank you in advance.

[Additional]
I want to get result something like this, but don't now how to apply it to html elements and render on browser.

```
const orderRule = ['Cat', 'Rabbit', 'Dog', 'Pig', 'Mouse'],
      array = ['Mouse','Rabbit', 'Pig', 'Dog', 'Cat'];

const sortArray = [...array].sort((a, b) => orderRule.indexOf(a) - orderRule.indexOf(b));
console.log(sortArray);
```

Comment: is that DOM created dynamically

Comment: Select the elements, and then sort them? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over your array using `$.each` and then use `append` to add div at particular position.

Here is demo code :

```js
var arrayData = [59, 56, 57];
//looping through array
$.each(arrayData, function() {
//append div at particular positon using data-value
  $(".selectize-input").append($("div [data-value=" + this + "]"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectize-input">
  <div class="item" data-value="56">Dog</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="57">Rabbit</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="59">Cat</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is simple code and worked like a charm. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm not quite sure if I fully understand the question. But if you're trying to dynamically render a div for each piece of data, you could try something like...

JS:

```
const arrayData = [
    {value:59, title:"Cat"},
    {value:56, title:"Dog"},
    {...}
]

arrayData.forEach((dataObject) => {
    $('.selectize-input').append(
        document.createElement('div')
            .innerHTML(dataObj.title)
            .attr('data-value', dataObj.value)
            .addClass('item')
    )          
}
```

I'm not really a jQuery person, so I'm not entirely sure that this will work, but I believe it will send you in the right direction.

First, I am making your array into an array of objects which include both the value of the item, but also the title of the item.

Then, I am using a forEach loop to run through each item and create a new div based on it. It appends these divs to the `.selectize-input`.

I hope it helps you.

I should say, the stuff that you're doing here is something that ReactJS is really good at. It's like a souped-up javascript that allows you to create and manipulate HTML elements really easily.

Check it out at https://reactjs.org/!

Answer (score 1):

1. If you only have the parent element in html and want to add the child div in sorted order then :

   const divList = [
       {value:59, title:"Cat"},
       {value:56, title:"Dog"}
   ]

   ```
     divList.forEach((obj) => {

       $("<div />")
           .html(obj.title)
           .attr('data-value', obj.value)
           .addClass('item')
           .appendTo( $('.selectize-input'))
   ```

   })

Codepen : https://codepen.io/AdityaDwivedi/pen/pojMYRr

2. If you already have the div element added in your html & you want to sort them up :

   `<div class="selectize-input">
     <div class="item" data-value="56" id="56">Dog</div>
           <div class="item" data-value="57" id="57">Rabbit</div>
           <div class="item" data-value="59" id="59">Cat</div>
   </div>`

`

```
const divOrder = ["59", "56", "57"]
    const orderedDiv = $('.selectize-input > div').sort((a, b) =>
    divOrder.indexOf(a.id) - divOrder.indexOf(b.id)
    ); 



  $('.selectize-input').empty()

orderedDiv.map((obj) =>{
  $("<div />")
            .html(orderedDiv[obj].innerHTML)
            .attr('data-value', orderedDiv[obj].value)
            .appendTo( $('.selectize-input'))})
```

`

Codepen : https://codepen.io/AdityaDwivedi/pen/QWjeopv?editors=1111